# Why is the corners returned from cv2.aruco.detectMarkers method smaller than the truth value?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm using an 800 * 800 pure black and white ideal marker image as the input. The marker is placed at the center of the image, the size is 500 * 500. So the truth value of the corners' coordinates would be [149.5 149.5], [149.5 649.5], [649.5 649.5], [149.5 649.5].

The parameters for sub-pixel refinement are defined in the input of `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers` method, the result returned is [149.61249 149.61249], [649.3875 149.61249], [649.3875 649.3875], [149.61249 649.3875], which is a little smaller than the truth.

The input image is a very simple and ideal image, I don't know why `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers` did not give the accurate result. Is there some factors that only appear in actual photography were considered?

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def plot_corners(corners):
    corners = corners.reshape([-1, 2])
    plt.plot(corners[:, 0].tolist() + [corners[0, 0]], corners[:, 1].tolist() + [corners[0, 1]])
    return


aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.extendDictionary(nMarkers=75, markerSize=3, randomSeed=1)
paras = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()
paras.cornerRefinementMethod = cv2.aruco.CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX
paras.cornerRefinementWinSize = 2

img0 = cv2.imread('../data/dev/d1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
corners, ids, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(img0, aruco_dict, parameters=paras)

print(corners[0])
plt.imshow(img0, cmap='gray')
plot_corners(corners[0])
plot_corners(np.array([[149.5, 149.5], [649.5, 149.5], [649.5, 649.5], [149.5, 649.5]]))
plt.legend(['detected corners', 'true corners'])
plt.show()
```

[`input image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNym8.png)
[`detected result`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBt8m.png)
[`top-left corner close-up`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irgm2.png)

I have tried other sub-pixel refinement method, including `cv2.aruco.CORNER_REFINE_CONTOUR` and `cv2.aruco.CORNER_REFINE_APRILTAG`, but none of them gave the accurate result.

Comment: You told the corner refinement process to allow a window size of 2 pixels, and you're complaining that it is less than 0.1 pixels off?

Comment: I have tried other window sizes, from 1 to 200, the result would be very very close to the truth value with a window size of 80. But I would like to know why the result would not be perfectly equal to the truth value, as the marker detection for the input image would be the easiest situation with common sense. Not complaining, just curious.

Comment: I still don't understand how you are getting fractional pixels out of this.  PNG images do not have fractional pixels.

Comment: The origin (0, 0) is placed at the center of the top-left pixel of the image in opencv sub-pixel coordinate system. The coordinates of the corners of each single pixel should be like (*.5, *.5).

Comment: But what's the point?  What POSSIBLE use is there in doing subpixel operations on an image that starts out integral?  What you're doing doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It will be used in our photogrammetry system, a stereo camera.  For an image captured by a real camera, the corners of a marker mostly will not happen to be at the center or border of a pixel. So the sub-pixel level detection result is needed to improve the accuracy.

Comment: How can you possibly know that?  Your CAMERA is only delivering integral pixels, and you cannot invent accuracy where it does not exist to begin with.  You cannot know the location of the target with more than integral pixel accuracy.  It's impossible.

Comment: The relative brightness can give more information about the corners location. It is like, if half of a pixel is inside the marker, the brightness should be 50% gray. The detection algorithm uses this information to locate the corner at the sub-pixel level.